# Assignment operator overloading with a C++ class template

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

I have a C++ class template for representing real- and complex valued 2D fields. I'd like to overload the assignment operator to achieve deep-copying the data from one field to another. For now, I've restricted the data to either `double` or `std::complex<double>`. This means there are 4 different cases to consider: `double`-to-`double`, `double`-to-`std::complex<double>`, `std::complex<double>`-to-`double` and `std::complex<double>`-to-`std::complex<double>`. I want to handle the `std::complex<double>`-to-`double` case by taking the real part of the complex value; for the other cases it's just a trivial assignment. I'm however struggling to get the code to compile. The following is a simple mock version that captures the issues:

```
#include <complex>

template<class T>
class Number {
  private:
  // should make Number<T>.m_value visible to Number<U>
  template<class U>
  friend class Number;
    T m_value;
  public:
    Number(const T value) : m_value{value} {
      // restricting the data
      static_assert(
        std::is_same<T, double>::value || std::is_same<T, std::complex<double>>::value,
        "Error: Number::Number: Only 'double' and 'std::complex<double>' are supported currently!"
      );
      // no copying allowed
      Number(const Number& orig) = delete;
    };
    // general case
    template<class U>
    Number<T>& operator=(const Number<U>& another) {
      m_value = another.m_value;
      return *this;
    }
};

// specialization
template<> Number<double>& Number<double>::operator=(const Number<std::complex<double>>& another) {
  m_value = std::real(another.m_value);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  const std::complex<double> I{0.0, 1.0};
  Number<double> n{0.0};
  Number<std::complex<double>> m{1.0 + I*2.0};
  n = m;
  return 0;
}
```

Compiler output:

```
g++    -c -g -std=c++14 -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o main.cpp
main.cpp:28:28: error: template-id ‘operator=<>’ for ‘Number<double>& Number<double>::operator=(const Number<std::complex<double> >&)’ does not match any template declaration
 template<> Number<double>& Number<double>::operator=(const Number<std::complex<double>>& another) {
                            ^
main.cpp:28:97: note: saw 1 ‘template<>’, need 2 for specializing a member function template
 template<> Number<double>& Number<double>::operator=(const Number<std::complex<double>>& another) {
                                                                                                 ^
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘Number<T>& Number<T>::operator=(const Number<U>&) [with U = std::complex<double>; T = double]’:
main.cpp:36:5:   required from here
main.cpp:23:15: error: cannot convert ‘const std::complex<double>’ to ‘double’ in assignment
       m_value = another.m_value;
               ^
```

I can't seem to figure out how to implement the assignment overloads. I have tried to find a solution for my problem (e.g. from "Similar questions") and have come across many helpful questions and answers, and have incorporated many things from them to my code. I however haven't found a solution to my specific problem and seem to be stuck. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: *This means there are 4 different cases to consider: double-to-double, double-to-std::complex<double>, std::complex<double>-to-double and std::complex<double>-to-std::complex<double>* -- This sounds like a bug haven.  The assignment operator will also be used by the compiler, probably without you knowing about it.  That's why you see functions such as `to_whatever` to do the conversion of one type to another, and not rely on assignment operators and casting operators.

Comment: Easy way to avoid the issue in this case is to always take `std::real`. It is the identity function for non-complex types.

Comment: @user17732522, but I can't take `std::real` when assigning `std::complex<double>` to `std::complex<double>` - I don't want to lose the imaginary part in that case.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, you might be right. But will I face the same compilation errors if I try to implement a general function and a specialized function for copying the data?

Comment: @PetriHirvonen Assignment between equal types is going to use the implicitly-defined copy assignment operator. It won't use your template assignment operator at all. By the way, it is very strange for a type to be copy-assignable, but not copy-constructible.

Comment: Also the declaration `Number(const Number& orig) = delete;` is misplaced in the wrong scope in your question.

Comment: @PetriHirvonen -- To the last point made, if a programmer can do this: `Foo f1; Foo f2; f2 = f1;` then they expect that this is also available: `Foo f1; Foo f2 = f1;`

Comment: @user17732522 and @PaulMcKenzie, thanks for the comments! I just wanted to create fields on which I could do some mathematical operations using operators such as `+=`, `-=`, `*=`, `/=` etc., but also wanted to prevent the creation of new ones from mathematical operations because the fields can be sizeable. I was thinking `=` would serve as a nice shorthand for overwriting one field with the data of another equally sized field, but I'll give up on that idea since it seems problematic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually says what it expects in the line:

```
main.cpp:28:97: note: saw 1 ‘template<>’, need 2 for specializing a member function template
```

You need one 'template<>' to specialize `T` in class template and one more to specialize `U` in member function template:

```
template<>
template<>
Number<double>& Number<double>::operator=(const Number<std::complex<double>>& another) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @dewaffled, It worked! The compiler may often say very directly what it wants, but it's a different story whether I understand... I definitely didn't guess that this is what was needed.